# Restrição de palavras em comentários

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uma galeria de imagens que nessa galeria terá comentários, os comentários já estão sendo enviados ao BD e retornando da forma que eu queria. Mas preciso fazer um filtro para os comentários, caso eles possuam algum palavrão o comentário não subir para o BD.

Exemplo:

```
<textarea name="comentario">
"Caso o usuários escreva algum palavrão aqui, o mesmo não deve ser enviado"
</textarea>
```

Existe alguma função PHP que faça isso?

Comment: Interessante mais talvez você devesse pensar em criar um moderador de comentários, pois, ás vezes mesmo que o palavrão em si não apareça na frase, ainda assim ela pode ser ofensiva devido seu contexto.

Answer (score 7):

É possível utilizar a função **[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)**, que retorna a posição de determinada string dentro de outra. No seu caso, você pode criar um array com palavrões e percorrer esse array verificando se existe ou não.

## Exemplo

```
<?php
    $frase = 'Caso o usuário fdp vsf escreva algum palavrão aqui, o mesmo não deve ser enviado';
    $palavrao = '';
    $palavroes  = array ('pqp', 'fdp','vsf');
     
    foreach ($palavroes as $value){
        $pos = strpos($frase, $value);
     
        if (!($pos === false))
            $palavrao = $palavrao.$value.'|';        
    }
     
    if (strlen($palavrao) > 1) {
           echo "Palavrões encontrados: ".$palavrao;
     } else {
           echo "Não tem palavrão";
       }
?>
```

Veja funcionando no [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZvrMN5).

Comment: Opa camarada, seu código está muito bom. Mas vi uma situação que ele pode não funcionar. Caso eu coloque nesse array a palavra "puta", ele vai identificar uma parte da palavra "disputa" como palavrão. Vou tentar incrementar algo no código para ver como pode ser resolvido esse pequeno "problema".

Comment: @DiChrist, realmente é um cenário que eu não pensei. Para evita-lo, basta inserir a palavra com "espaços" no inicio e fim, teoricamente resolveria.

Comment: Beleza camarada, vou testar. Se não me  engano, cheguei a fazer um código parecido com o seu, mas usei a função explode no php para resolver. Até onde testei tava legal, mas vai que tem algum cenário que eu também não tenha pensado hahaha. De qualquer forma, sua resposta está ótima! +1

Answer (score 5):

Expressão regular também pode ser uma outra saída para isso. Fiz algo para detectar sites com urls impróprias há pouco tempo, dessa forma:

```
#blacklist.php
return array(
    '(.*)\.(xxx)',
    '4tube\.com',
    'clickme\.net',
    'cnnamador\.com',
    'extremefuse\.com',
    'fakku\.net',
    'fux\.com(?!\.br)', //Com .br é de advogados
    'heavy-r\.com', 
    'kaotic\.com', 
    'xhamster\.com',
    'porndoe\.com',
    'pornocarioca\.com',
    'rapebait\.net',
    'redtube\.com',
    'sex\.com',
    'vidmax\.com',
    'wipfilms\.net',
    'xvideos\.(com|net)',
    'porntube\.com',
);
```

Daí utilizo assim numa função:

```
public static function isBlockedHost($url)
{

    $keywords = (array) include 'blacklist.php';

    foreach ($keywords as $regex) {

        if (preg_match("/{$regex}/i", $url) > 0) return true;

    }

    return false;
}
```

Pense que, se eu pude fazer isso com hosts, você também pode fazer isso com palavras que deseja bloquear. À medida que forem surgindo, você pode adicioná-las num array.

Comment: Eu prefiro expressão regular também. Mas sou leigo no assunto. Até porquê não tive a oportunidade de usar ainda.

Answer (score 5):

Seria interessante além de ter um bloqueio `serve-side` ter um bloqueio `cliente-side` para que o usuário possa fazer as devidas correções é enviar o comentário sem nenhuma palavra proibida.

Se você preza por um texto legível, fazer isto se torna indispensável, visto que a exclusão de uma palavra x poderá alterar o nexo do comentário.

Aqui vai um exemplo em `js` do bloqueio, basicamente ele só irá enviar para o `php` se não tiver nenhuma palavra proibida. você pode  melhorar a mensagem de retorno para o seu usuário.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var list = ['noob', 'lammer'];

function blackList() {
  var texto = document.getElementById('texto');
  var tamTexto = texto.innerHTML.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (texto.innerHTML.indexOf(list[i]) >= 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

if (blackList()) {
  console.log("Comentario ok, envie para o php");
} else {
  console.log("Meça suas palavras parca!");
};
```

```html
<p id="texto">Você é um noob, e seu primo um lammer</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode se utilizar também uma tabela na base de dados.

Cria uma tabela, por exemplo:

### Palavras

> Colunas
>
> ID | Palavra Errada | Palavra Certa

Cadastre todas a palavras erradas na coluna **Palavra Errada** e na outra coluna **Palavra Certa** cadastra uma palavra que você quer que substitua a errada ou apenas deixe em branco.

Quando for cadastrar a mensagem do usuário na tabela faça um **while** nessa tabela usando o `str_replace` na variável do texto.

### Pseudo-Code

```
TABELA = SELECT TABLE PALAVRAS

while TABELA
    $mensagem = STR_REPLACE (TABELA[PALAVRA_ERRADA], TABELA[PALAVRA_CERTA], $mensagem)

ECHO $mensagem
```

Assim ele retira todas as palavras inapropriadas.

Answer (score 2):

No Codeigniter tem o helper text que tem uma função [word_censor](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html#word_censor) que remove ou altera palavras de um texto, pode usar somente essa função em sua aplicação.

```
/**
 * Word Censoring Function
 *
 * Supply a string and an array of disallowed words and any
 * matched words will be converted to #### or to the replacement
 * word you've submitted.
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the text string
 * @param   string  the array of censoered words
 * @param   string  the optional replacement value
 * @return  string
 */
if ( ! function_exists('word_censor'))
{
    function word_censor($str, $censored, $replacement = '')
    {
        if ( ! is_array($censored))
        {
            return $str;
        }

        $str = ' '.$str.' ';

        // \w, \b and a few others do not match on a unicode character
        // set for performance reasons. As a result words like über
        // will not match on a word boundary. Instead, we'll assume that
        // a bad word will be bookeneded by any of these characters.
        $delim = '[-_\'\"`(){}<>\[\]|!?@#%&,.:;^~*+=\/ 0-9\n\r\t]';

        foreach ($censored as $badword)
        {
            if ($replacement != '')
            {
                $str = preg_replace("/({$delim})(".str_replace('\*', '\w*?', preg_quote($badword, '/')).")({$delim})/i", "\\1{$replacement}\\3", $str);
            }
            else
            {
                $str = preg_replace("/({$delim})(".str_replace('\*', '\w*?', preg_quote($badword, '/')).")({$delim})/ie", "'\\1'.str_repeat('#', strlen('\\2')).'\\3'", $str);
            }
        }

        return trim($str);
    }
}
```

exemplo de uso:

```
echo word_censor('Texto do comentario com um palavrao', array('palavrao'), '---');
```

exemplo rodando no **[ideone](https://ideone.com/ceHXdz)**